# Paypal Classic API error codes processing in PHP

Tags: paypal

Here we have [long list of paypal errors](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3G0T01AR)

This list is asolutely unusable. For some errors "Short Message" should be shown to the user, for some errors "Long Message". Part of errors should be described to users in some cases we have to redirect user to Paypal. Can anybody suggest php library to process all these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any such library exists at this time (and yes, some Paypal errors leave much to be desired). The closest I could find was this [JSON Object](https://gist.github.com/jacobwegner/2701572/), but it doesn't improve on the messages, only rehashes them. Maybe consider creating one and putting it in GitHub for public use?